# Why is scanf being performed 11 times?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int marks[10];
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ", &marks[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (i=0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", marks[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: C Language Array]
Clearly, the first loop condition should run only 10 times but instead it asks me for an 11th value. Does anyone know about this? Or is it just one of the many weird behaviours of C?

In the second loop it's working the way I want!

Comment: remove extra space: `scanf("%d ")` ==> `scanf("%d")`

Comment: Don't post images of code. Just copy the code into the question.

Comment: Ok, Actually this is my first time posting in stackoverflow so pardon.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In This case space after %d is format specifier so it's take 2 argument with space as separator.

```
scanf("%d %d", &marks[i], &marks[i+1]); => 1 2
scanf("%d ", &marks[i]); => 1 2
scanf("%d", &marks[i]);  => 1
```